# Como usar JavaScript para bloquear uma tecla do teclado e exibir alerta no campo sobre a tecla recomendada?

Tags: javascript

Como faço um JavaScript para que bloqueie o uso de vírgula `,` dentro do campo e na mesma hora também faça uma notificação informado que apenas o ponto `.` é permitido e também verifique se o que o usuário digitou está correto.

Não tenho muito conhecimento em JavaScript e não achei muito sobre isso, o máximo que cheguei a achar foi `onKeyCode` e teve outro que eu esqueci mas não consegui nada.

**Exemplo:**
 peso atual: 70.80

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode vincular um evento no elemento de `input`

Exemplo:

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keypress', function(evt) {
    if (evt.key == ',') {
        evt.preventDefault()
        alert('Tecla inválida');
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

`document.querySelector('input')` vai te retornar o elemento que você quer vincular

`addEventListener` vincula um `callback` para um determinado evento, no exemplo o evento vinculado é `keypress`

`function(evt){ console.log(evt.key); }` é o `callback`, a ação que vai ser executada quando o evento ocorrer.

Você pode chamar o método `preventDefault()` para impedir a ação padrão do evento

Comment: Talvez adicionar `evt.preventDefault()` dentro do `if` para bloquear, de fato, o uso da vírgula?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, editado, tinha esquecido desse detalhe :)

Answer (score 1):

Tem um evento do jQuery que se chama keyPress, por parametro você passa uma função com um if se a tecla da virgula foi apertada ou seja :

Ex:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 188) {
        alert('You pressed a virgula!');
    }
});
```

188 é a , do teclado. esse site tem o valor de todos: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/keycodes.htm

Ve se consegue implementar se não conseguir me responde aqui

Comment: Tem um site muito legal, no qual você aperta a tecla e ele mostra o código correspondente, veja [keycode.info](http://keycode.info/)